# Python 2.7.10 csv how to write each version of an iterating output in a new row

Tags: python, excel, csv, dictionary

I want to write an iterating output, with each version in a new row of the csv. I have tried this:

```
#matching questions
for ind1,key1 in enumerate(file1):
    for ind2,key2 in enumerate(file2):
        ques1 = file1[key1]
        ques2 = file2[key2]
        match_ratio = difflib.SequenceMatcher (None, ques1, ques2).ratio()
        n = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb"))
        n.writerow([key1, ques1, key2, ques2, match_ratio])
```

As you can see I am trying to match two strings each from a different dictionary and then I want to output the key and value of each and the match ratio into a csv file so I can work with the output in excel. However, only the last versions of each variable is getting output and I have no clue why.

Why is it not outputting the variables into a new row in the csv each time? What should I do to make this happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You open the file after each match in the "wb" mode. Try the "a" mode or bring the line with csv.writer outside the loops.

Comment: Tried to open the file in "a" mode but now there is a blank row after each row of output. I will be working with 1000s of questions, this would make the file too big. Any way to solve this?

Comment: You should move the opening and instantiation of `csv.writer` outside the loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @amal-ts said, you should use append mode to open file.

And opening file in every loop is bad idea, so you should consider using `with`

```
with open("output.csv", "ab") as f:
    for ind1,key1 in enumerate(file1):
        for ind2,key2 in enumerate(file2):
            ques1 = file1[key1]
            ques2 = file2[key2]
            match_ratio = difflib.SequenceMatcher (None, ques1, ques2).ratio()
            n = csv.writer(f)
            n.writerow([key1, ques1, key2, ques2, match_ratio])
```

Finally, you should check `match_ratio` value to check your blank row problem.

Comment: For some reason using this block of code resolved the blank line issue as well, weird...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is rewriting the data on each iteration, instead open the file in append mode.

Comment: Yeah it is working well now except there is a blank row after every row with output. How should I fix this?

Comment: Can you print the writerow() content and see where is it getting the blank line?